# Not able to toggle <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a button that will toggle a div which contains certain replies to comments. I want to be able to hide and show the replies to comments on clicking the button. And the "show all replies" button will only be shown if there are more than one replies to a comment. But whenever I click the button, nothing happens. The console also doesn't show any errors. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
if($numberOfReplies>=1){
?>
    <button id="repliestogglebutton">show all replies</button>

<?php
}               
?>

<div class="allreplies" id="allrepliesdiv" style="display:none;">
  (all replies to a comment are displayed here)
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#repliestogglebutton").click(function() {
        jQuery("#allrepliesdiv").toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code should work, With the available information we can help much, you need to divulge more information

Comment: you can write a class to show/hide and toggle it on button click using $("#allrepliesdiv").toggleClass("class-name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").click(function(){
   $(".answer-container").toggleClass("visible");
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.button:hover{
   background-color:#FFEEEE;
}

.visible{
  display:block !important;
}

.answer-container{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
Show all
</div>
<div class="answer-container">
Extra Comments
<br />
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

I used a div for the button but you can use anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your given code looks fine to me. There might be any thing else causing the problem.
PFA. A working code you may test in a new file. ("slow" is the applied animation on toggle. )

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="repliestogglebutton">show all replies</button>
 <div class="allreplies" id="allrepliesdiv" style="display:none;">
  <p>Comment 1 </p>
  <p>Comment 2 </p>
  <p>Comment 3 </p>
  <p>Comment 4 </p>
</div>

<script>
  $( "#repliestogglebutton" ).click(function() {
    $( "#allrepliesdiv").toggle( "slow" );
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any one method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#repliestogglebutton").click(function() {
        jQuery("#allrepliesdiv").slideToggle();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#repliestogglebutton").click(function() {
        $("#allrepliesdiv").slideToggle();
    });
});

//If jquery conflict then use this method
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(document).ready(function(){
     $j("#repliestogglebutton").click(function() {
         $j("#allrepliesdiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: if this code is not working so please check console. If any error on console  then code not run.